# To insert to Pg by Psycopg

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg

**How can you fix the SQL-statement in Python?**

The db connection works. However, `cur.execute` returns   *none* which is false.

**My code**

```
import os, pg, sys, re, psycopg2

try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='tk' host='localhost' port='5432' user='naa' password='123'")
except: print "unable to connect to db"
cur = conn.cursor()

print cur.execute("SELECT * FROM courses")     # problem here
```

The SQL-command in Psql returns me the correct output.
I can similarly run `INSERT` in Psql, but not by Python's scripts.
I get no warning/error to /var/log.

Possible bugs are

1. **cursor()**, seems to be right however
2. **the syntax of the method *connect()***, seems to be ok however

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call one of the `fetch` methods on `cur` (fetchone, fetchmany, fetchall) to actually get the results of the query.

You should probably have a read through the a [tutorial](http://www.amk.ca/python/writing/DB-API.html) for [DB-API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: **Which method do you need to run to put the data to the database?** `cur.insert("INSERT INTO courses (course) VALUES ( %s )""", [data])` is not working for me.

Comment: Check `psycopg.paramstyle` to see which parameterisation style you're supposed to use with that module; it is unfortunate that DB-API allows several possibilities rather than standardising on one. I *think* `psycopg` is supposed to be using `'pyformat'`, in which case `cur.execute('INSERT INTO courses (course) VALUES(%(course)s)', {'course': var})` would be the syntax.

Comment: "is not working" is a bit vague - does it raise an exception? Also, I don't think psycopg2 autocommits by default (unlike psql) - you'll need to call `conn.commit()` after inserting the row, for it to become visible to other sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call `cur.fetchall()` method (or one of other `fetch*()` methods) to get results from query.